# What is it called when you begin to exhibit similar personality traits as someone close to you?

Tags: terminology, semantics, literature, psychology, psycholinguistics

Especially someone you live with, whether that be a partner, roommate, family, etc. I feel like there’s a psychological term for this. Like how we pick up little quirks in passing, or how the behaviors of someone we’re close to tend to rub off on us. There’s a term and I can’t for the life of me find it. “Influence” is as close as I’ve gotten but that’s not the word I’m looking for.

Comment: "Mirroring" might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "behavioral mimicry", though it's more of a biological term.

Comment: Hi Mel, welcome to our site. Did you make up the expression *"behavioral mimicry"* or are you drawing from existing knowledge? If it's the latter, please [edit] your post to add a reference and preferably a link. This will help distinguish what could be an authoritative answer (which we encourage, and reward with upvotes) from mere personal opinion (which belongs on a discussion forum rather than a formal Q&A site like ours, and is strongly discouraged). For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Close proximity effect** is the closest term I could find for this condition.

As per [riskology.co](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://riskology.co/proximity-effect/&ved=2ahUKEwi90t6n7YjmAhVlwTgGHeJgCbgQFjALegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw07H-t_WSqH1BMyIOylf7kO): You’ll mirror the habits of the people you spend the most time with.

Comment: That does not seem like an established term. In sociology, there is something called [proximity principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_principle), but it refers to "the tendency for individuals to form interpersonal relations with those who are close by" and it, although related, doesn't exactly cover OP's scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest intentional mimic or unintentional mimic as the case may be